# Add ul to its children with get_posts

Tags: get-posts

I want to add a ul to the list when a page have a child, Im making a foreach on all the post_types so i don't think that i can use something like [wp_list_pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages). I have been trying to sort this out but just ended upp with this:

```
// Check for children
$children = array(); 
foreach ( $values as $post ) {
  if( $post->post_parent ) {
    $children[] = $post->ID;
  }
}
foreach ( $values as $post ) {
  setup_postdata( $post );
     if( in_array( $post->ID, $children ) ) {
        $output .= '<ul>';
           $output .= '<li data-id="'. $post->ID .'" data-area="'. $area['area'] .'"><p>'. get_the_title() .'</p><span>'. __('Child', 'blocks') .'</span></li>';
        $output .= '</ul>';
     } else {
        $output .= '<li data-id="'. $post->ID .'" data-area="'. $area['area'] .'"><p>'. get_the_title() .'</p><span>'. __('Parent', 'blocks') .'</span></li>';
     }  
  wp_reset_postdata();                              
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//first let's separate all the top level pages & child pages
$top_lvl = array();
$children = array();
foreach ( $values as $post ) {
  if( $post->post_parent ) {
    $children[$post->post_parent][] = $post;
  } else {
    $top_lvl[] = $post;
  }
}

//now we have all top level pages in $top_lvl
//& we can access their child pages at $children[<top_lvl_ID>]
//now lets loop through top_lvl pages & display them
foreach ( $top_lvl as $post ) {
  setup_postdata( $post );
  $output .= '<li data-id="'. $post->ID .'" data-area="'. $area['area'] .'"><p>'. get_the_title() .'</p><span>'. __('Parent', 'blocks') .'</span></li>';
  //check if this post has children
  if( isset( $children[$post->ID] ) ) {
    foreach( $children[$post->ID] as $post ) {
      //do something with children here
    }
  }
}
//can't forget to reset the global data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Thanks @Mridul, But the soulution dosent work the whole way.. I want it do be:
`<ul> 
<li>Parent</li>
<ul>
  <li>Child</li>
  <li>Child</li>
  <li>Child</li>
</ul>
</ul>`

Now i only get Undefined offset: on `foreach( $children[$post->ID as $post])`

Comment: Okey i sorted it out now, Your code worked great. But i had some old pages and they needed to be saved again.. weird. Thanks

Comment: The error was here- `foreach( $children[$post->ID as $post])` should be `foreach( $children[$post->ID] as $post)`